# ASP.NET page level variable

Tags: asp.net, scope

What's the best way (if there is a way) to define a variable for use by controls on one page, but should be disposed of after navigating away from that page? Is there anything like `HttpContext.Current.Items` that only persists per page?

Comment: Can you just define a variable on the class that inherits from `Page` itself? You can retrieve the `Page` on which the controls exist from within the control itself (user or otherwise) via the `Page` property, cast it to the sub-class type, and access the variable. You could also subclass `UserControl` if it's just the user controls that are going to need it.

Comment: That sounds good, I'll try that if there's no 'easy' way to do it, thanks

Comment: It *is* possible; I didn't mean to ask whether it was -- I was suggesting it as a solution.

Comment: Ah, just seen in Intellisense that there is already a `Page.Items` - so I'll give that a go

Answer (score 2):

There's a thing called Viewstate
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

that may provide the functionality you want. If not, try to be more specific on how do you want to use those variables.